# How do I redirect from .html/ to .html with Htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

**How do I redirect from .html/ to .html ?**

I redirected my old Blog Directory to the News Directory but it does it with a Slash at the end after .html

I tried those two lines in my .htaccess file but it did nothing...

```
RewriteRule (.*\.html)/$ $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule (.*\.html)/$ $1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Are you sure you enabled the RewriteEngine? `RewriteEngine On`. Also, you have a trailing '/', meaning it would only match .html/ instead of .html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need this below your RewriteEngine on**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R] # <- for test, for prod use [L,R=301]
```

or

```
RewriteRule .*\.html\/$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

or

```
 RewriteRule (.*)\.html\/$ http:\/\/www.example.com$1.html [R=301,L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html\/$ $1.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I haven't tried this but this might help someone else, thanks  :)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my problem:

**You need this below your RewriteEngine on**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R] # <- for test, for prod use [L,R=301]
```

Comment: For future reference, if you find the answer yourself within 5 minutes of posting, you probably should try a bit more before posting. Asking here should be the last action when you really have exhausted all other options.